# Stop Loss And entry strategy not triggering Correctly

Tags: pine-script

This strategy works fine by itself but not when I add the stop loss logic.
Long entrys are instantly being exited(stop loss) but my shorts hit their stop loss perfectly. However shorts do not always enter a position when they should be. Im not sure what Im doing wrong.I think there are orders floating around not canceled or triggering incorrectly. This is an intra candle stop loss.

```
//@version=4
strategy("My TEMA Strategy+SL,TP", overlay=true, pyramiding=0)
//TEMA
xPrice = ohlc4
Length = input(14, minval=1)

xEMA1 = ema(xPrice, Length)
xEMA2 = ema(xEMA1, Length)
xEMA3 = ema(xEMA2, Length)

Length2=input(28, minval=1)

xxEMA1 = ema(xPrice, Length2)
xxEMA2 = ema(xxEMA1, Length2)
xxEMA3 = ema(xxEMA2, Length2)

FastMA = 3 * xEMA1 - 3 * xEMA2 + xEMA3
SlowMA = 3 * xxEMA1 - 3 * xxEMA2 + xxEMA3

longcond = crossover (FastMA,SlowMA)
shortcond = crossunder (FastMA,SlowMA)


plot(FastMA,  title="TEMA1",color=color.green,linewidth=2)
plot(SlowMA, title="TEMA2",color=color.red,linewidth=2)

if (longcond)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)


if (shortcond)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)



//Long Short itra candle stop loss. Shorts working Longs not working
intra_stop_level = input(1, title="Intra Candle Stop %")
intra_stop_long = strategy.position_avg_price*(1-intra_stop_level/100)
intra_stop_short = strategy.position_avg_price*(1+intra_stop_level/100)

strategy.exit("Stop LossL","Long",stop=intra_stop_long,limit=1)
strategy.exit("Stop LossS","Short",stop=intra_stop_short,limit=1)
```

Comment: Why is `limit=1` used? It places price to sell (for long) and if an assets you are applying the strategy to has usual price greater than 1, then the asset will be sold with the very next tick.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
Yea you are right limit=1 isnt needed in my case, the stop loss logic isnt my code but I still have the same problem if I remove it or not. The stop original author has limit=a, limit=b) maybe thats what im missing. I just want to backtest with stop loss trigger at the exact tick at the x% from my entry.

Comment: If you want to exit in X ticks from entry, then you should use `profit`/`loss`. I'll give you an example below.

Answer (score 0):

Using number of ticks for exit from a position

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)

TICKS_TO_EXIT = 10
MAX_LOSS_IN_TICKS = 15

strategy.entry("Id", strategy.long, when=bar_index % 2 == 1)
strategy.exit("exitId", "Id", profit=TICKS_TO_EXIT, loss=MAX_LOSS_IN_TICKS)
```

Exit by profit from entry price:

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)

long_condition = bar_index % 5 == 4

entryPrice = 0.0
entryPrice := entryPrice[1]

if long_condition and na(strategy.position_avg_price)
    strategy.entry("longId", strategy.long)
    entryPrice := close

limitPrice = entryPrice * 1.05
strategy.exit("exitId", "longId", limit=limitPrice)
```

Comment: I messed around with ticks a bit, the problem is I need to backtest with a stop loss that exits at a fixed% from entry , intra-candle. When I use stop= it often paints an exit at the same time as an entry(but not every time). With loss= it doesnt have that issue and triggers intra-candle but Im not sure how to convert ticks into percent from entry and back to ticks again. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it's impossible to do exactly as you wish, but we can emulate such strategy, with some restrictions. I updated the answer. Check it out.